# Unresolvable contact point, can't connect to azure cosmos db database

Tags: python, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb

I was setting up a new server to play around with the Cassandra api and cosmosdb. I was following Microsoft quick start guide in connecting to the server and its tutorial and after completing all the steps I am recieving an `cassandra.UnresolvableContactPoints` error.

I've tried checking my contact point address and trying different variations. I have also made a new version of the server and tried the new contact point that it generated and I am still receiving the same error.

***This is in the main

```
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(
        username=cfg.config['username'], password=cfg.config['password'])
cluster = Cluster([cfg.config['contactPoint']], port = cfg.config['port'], auth_provider=auth_provider, ssl_options=ssl_opts
)

session = cluster.connect()
```

**This is in the config file

```
config = {
         'username': '',

         'password': '',

         'contactPoint': 'sreepathyvarcassandra.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com:10350',

         'port':'10350'
         }
```

I'm receiving a traceback error at the cfg.config['port'] line and it states that it is a unresolvable contact point. Instead it should be connecting to cosmosdb and inserting values.

Comment: Since the post is specified in the port settings you shouldn't need the port also specified in the contact point. Did you try using just the uri? Try `sreepathyvarcassandra.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com` or `https://sreepathyvarcassandra.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com`

Comment: I have tried that, when I run it without the port like [sreepathyvarcassandra.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com] I receive an error in my `session = cluster.connect()` saying I have a. TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str. When using https:// like you suggested I get the same error as before. @NickChapsas

Comment: Without the stack trace it is hard to know, but I think that the issue is that you are providing port as a string instead of an int. Maybe try passing int(cfg.config['port']) ?